# Hacer peticiones http get aninadas en Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, http-get

me ha tocado hacer una funcionalidad en javascript del cual no tengo mucha experiencia. El problema es el siguiente:
tengo que hacer una petición que me devuelve una lista de diccionarios con unos `userId` que representan a una persona además de otros datos. A continuación necesito hacer otra llamada get para conseguir el `username` de ese identificador y guardarlo en ese primer array de diccionarios para representarlo en el front. Como es posible que en el primer array, varias posiciones tengan el mismo `userId` me gustaría ahorrar en llamadas guardando esta información en alguna variable pero tengo problemas para acceder a algunas variables del codigo y con la sincronía.
El código es el siguiente:

```
messages;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authString = localStorage.getItem('authString');

    this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/message/', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization": "Basic " + this.authString
      })
    }).subscribe(response => {
      this.messages = response;

      let id_names = []
      for (let i in response) {
        if (!id_names.find(id_names => id_names.id === response[i]["id"])) { //si no lo tenemos ya
          let user_res = this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/users/' + response[i]["userId"], {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              "Authorization": "Basic " + this.authString
            })
          }).subscribe(res => {
        
            this.messages[i]["username"]=res["username"]
            id_names.push({id:response[i]["id"], username:res["username"]})
            console.log(id_names)
          });   
        }
        else { // si lo tenemos en id_names
          //No llega nunca a esta parte
        }
      };

    })
  };
```

El problema es que se ejecuta primero varias veces el primer get y luego el segundo por lo que no se evalúa la condición del if con `id_names` relleno.
Además las variables mueren fuera de los subscribes y no se cómo sacarlas.
¿Alguna forma diferente de hacer el http.get? ¿Alguna forma de acceder a las variables desde fuera?

Gracias.

Comment: Utiliza promesas, es decir, convierte tus obervables en promesas y utiliza la sintaxis de async await.

Answer (score 1):

Ejemplo de peticiones http ejecutadas secuencia usando await y promesas:

```
// await debe usarse dentro de una función que sea async
async test() {

  // petición http usando observable
  this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(r => {
    console.log(r);
  });

  // peticiones http usando promesas y await
  // el operador await espera hasta que se resuelva la promesa
  // los datos devueltos por la petición están en la  variable
  // respuesta
  let respuesta1 = await this.http 
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .toPromise(); // convertir la petición a promesa
  
  // la primera petición finalizó, sigue la segunda
  let respuesta2 = await this.http
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .toPromise();

  
}
```